# How to add months dynamically which is stored in database as a header in excel file while exporting using laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

Suppose I have items in database which is stored from an Excel file. All the items should be below the header of the months. I have also stored months from the file in the database. So, I want those months to be the header of those items and it's related records. In simple words, I want the header to be dynamic. This is what I have done.

I have tried many code scripts but nothing works. Like Laravel, Excel etc. Can anyone suggest me a good approach?

```
public function test(){
    $data = Item::where('category_id',7)->get()->toArray();
    $data2 = month::all();

    $itemsArray[] = ['Category Id','Item Name','Created At','Updated At'];

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        // dd($value);
        $itemsArray[] = array(

            'Category Id' => $value['category_id'],
            'Item Name' => $value['name'],
            'Created At' => $value['created_at'],
            'Updated At' => $value['updated_at'],
        );

    }

    // Generate and return the spreadsheet
        Excel::create('Items', function($excel) use ($itemsArray) {

            // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
            $excel->setTitle('Items');

            // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the items array
            $excel->sheet('Items', function($sheet) use ($itemsArray) {

                $cellRange = 'A1:D1';
                // $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D4')
                    // ->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
                $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setBold( true );
                $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize( '15' );
                $sheet->setBorder($cellRange, 'thick' );
                $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray(array(
                       'fill' => array(
                           // 'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                           'color' => array('rgb' => 'A5D9FF')
                       )
                   ));
                $sheet->fromArray($itemsArray, null, 'A1', false, false);
            });
            $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('Dev505');
            $excel->setDescription('Items file');

        })->download('xlsx');
  }
```

I need help for getting the actual result.

[image: These months are coming from database]

[image: Here I want the header to be months dynamically]

Comment: 0

I think you need to clarify more the question. So you want those months to be the header of those items and it's related records.. means that you need a column for each month?

Comment: Actually I want those months to be the header only. Means that those months should appear only once in the header and the rest of record will appear below the month header or row.

Comment: Let say, I have 12 months record, so every month record should appear from it's corresponding month. The months and record and items i have already saved to database. The problem is only in exporting to the desire format.

Comment: So 12 columns, one for each month?

Comment: Ok, you solved.. great!

Comment: Why did you add the spelling errors again that I fixed for you?

Comment: I didn't notice sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the actual code which I have used for excel file. I have solved my problem. Thanks and yeah I am posting this code, if anyone can get help from it.

```
public function export(){

    $data = Category::all();

    foreach ($data as $value) {

        $value['items'] = Item::where('category_id',$value['id'])->get();

        foreach ($value['items'] as $vl) {

            $vl['record'] = Record::where('item_id',$vl['id'])->get();
        }
    }

    $data2 = month::pluck('id','month');

    foreach ($data2 as $key => $value) {

        $m[] = $key;
    }

    array_unshift($m, 'Categories'); //Insert new element at the start of array
    array_push($m, 'Total');

    $itemsArray[] = $m;

    foreach ($data as $value) {

        $itemsArray[] = array(

            $itemsArray[0][0] => $value['name'],
            // $itemsArray[0][13] => 'Total',
        );

        foreach ($value['items'] as $val) {

            $records_array = [];
            $i =  0;

            foreach ($val['record'] as $val5) {

                $recordval = $val5['value'];
                $records_array[$i] = $val5['value'];
                $i++;
            }

            $itemsArray[] = array(

                $itemsArray[0][0] => $val['name'],
                $itemsArray[0][1] => $records_array[0],
                $itemsArray[0][2] => $records_array[1],
                $itemsArray[0][3] => $records_array[2],
                $itemsArray[0][4] => $records_array[3],
                $itemsArray[0][5] => $records_array[4],
                $itemsArray[0][6] => $records_array[5],
                $itemsArray[0][7] => $records_array[6],
                $itemsArray[0][8] => $records_array[7],
                $itemsArray[0][9] => $records_array[8],
                $itemsArray[0][10] => $records_array[9],
                $itemsArray[0][11] => $records_array[10],
                $itemsArray[0][12] => $records_array[11],
                // $itemsArray[0][13] => 'Total',
            );

        }

    }

    // Generate and return the spreadsheet
    Excel::create('Items', function($excel) use ($itemsArray) {

        // Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
        $excel->setTitle('Items');

        // Build the spreadsheet, passing in the items array
        $excel->sheet('Items', function($sheet) use ($itemsArray) {
            $cellRange = 'A1:M1';
            $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setBold( true );
            $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize( '12' );
            $sheet->setBorder($cellRange, 'thin' );
            $sheet->getStyle($cellRange)->applyFromArray(array(
                   'fill' => array(
                       // 'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                       'color' => array('rgb' => 'A5D9FF')
                   )
               ));
            $sheet->fromArray($itemsArray, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
        $excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('Dev505');
        $excel->setDescription('Items file');

    })->download('xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Akhtar i suggest use to kindly install the Carbon package
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Try by updating the below code.

```
$data = Item::where('category_id',7)->get(); // removed toArray()
$data2 = month::all();
$itemsArray[] = ['Category Id','Item Name','Created At','Updated At'];

foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {

    $itemsArray[] = array(
        'month' => Carbon::now()->addMonth($key)->format('m-Y');
        'Category Id' => $value['category_id'],
        'Item Name' => $value['name'],
        'Created At' => $value['created_at'],
        'Updated At' => $value['updated_at'],
    );

}
```

Comment: No Bro, you didn't get my point. I have stored months randomly in database according to the file, the order of the months are different. I don't want to include the Carbon months. But I have solved my problem by myself. I will update my own code for other people to get help from. Thanks anyway